# Urns version of Laplace's law of succession

Tags: probability

I'm trying to prove urns version of Laplace's law of succession my professor suggested. Laplace's law states that the chance that the next trial is a success given $j$ successes out of the first $n$ is $\frac{(j+1)}{(n+2)}$. Here is how the problem states:

"If we have $n+k+1$ urns and urn $i$ has $i$ balls labeled $1$ and $n+k-i$ labeled zero. We pick an urn at random and draw $n$ balls from it without replacement say $j$ of them are ones. Show that the conclusion of Laplace's law holds for this setup. In other word, the chance that the next ball is a one is $\frac{(j+1)}{(n+2)}$."

I've proved one version of the law, which close to this version [An elementary version of Laplace's Method of Succession](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102417/an-elementary-version-of-laplaces-method-of-succession). I tried to use similar approach but somehow my answer always in form of $k$ and I can't get rid of it. What is the intuition behind this $k$? Is it just to increase the complexity of the problem, or it has some meaning behind it?

Comment: That can't be right; for $j=n=0$ it should be $1/2$, not $1$. I seem to remember the denominator should be $n+2$.

Comment: The $i$th urn always has $i$ balls labeled $1$? That somehow sounds odd.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be the random variable indicating the label of the urn picked, $J$ the number of ones picked (after picking $n$ balls), and $X$ the event that the next ball is one. We know that
$$
P(J = j \mid I = i) = \frac{\binom{i}{j}\binom{n+k-i}{n-j}}{\binom{n + k}{n}}
= \frac{\binom{j+(i-j)}{i-j}\binom{n+k-j-(i-j)}{k-(i-j)}}{\binom{n+k}{n}}
$$
and
$$
P(X \mid I = i, J = j) =
\begin{cases}
0 & ; i \le j \\
\frac{i-j}k & ; j \le i \le k + j
\end{cases}
$$
Compute $P(I = i \mid J = j)$ from
$$
P(I = i \mid J = j) = \frac{P(I = i, J = j)}{\sum_{\tilde i}P(I = \tilde i, J = j)} =
\frac{P(J = j \mid I = i)}{\sum_{\tilde i} P(J = j \mid I = \tilde i)}
$$
where we use $P(I = i) = \frac{1}{n + k + 1}$ in the last equation. Then,
\begin{align*}
P(X \mid J = j) & = \sum_{i} P(X \mid I = i, J = j) P(I = i \mid J = j) \\
& = \sum_{i=j}^{k+j} \frac{i-j}k \frac{P(J = j \mid I = i)}{\sum_{\tilde i} P(J = j \mid I = \tilde i)} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=j}^{k+j}(i-j)P(J = j \mid I = i)}{k \sum_{i=j}^{k+j} P(J = j \mid I = i)} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=j}^{k+j}(i-j)\binom{i}{j}\binom{n+k-i}{n-j}}{k \sum_{i=j}^{k+j} \binom{i}{j}\binom{n+k-i}{n-j}} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^k i \binom{j+i}{i}\binom{n-j+(k-i)}{k-i}}{k\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{j+i}{i}\binom{n-j+(k-i)}{k-i}}
\end{align*}
I don't know how to make this into the desired expression $\frac{j+1}{n+2}$. Putting $k = 1$ seems to work though.